# Terraform code with the json format are not supported

Tags: aws-event-bridge

`In the Terraform for creating the Event bridge with getting alert through SNS topic when the ENI getting modification for this the Json format have not validated at the terraform running time

`event_pattern = <<EOF { "source":"aws.config", "detail-type":"Config Configuration Item Change", "detail": { "messageType":"ConfigurationItemChangeNotification", "configurationItem": { "resourceType":"AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface", "resourceId":"eni-030512620140c240d","eni-0626261dd4743a0fc" } } } EOF`

At the final stage it through the error as

I need the code to get Terraform validation `

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid.

```
{
    "source": "aws.config",
    "detail-type": "Config Configuration Item Change",
    "detail": {
        "messageType": "ConfigurationItemChangeNotification",
        "configurationItem": {
            "resourceType": "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface",
            "resourceId": "eni-030512620140c240d",
            "eni-0626261dd4743a0fc" <---- This is incorrect
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this is what you want:

```
{
    "source": "aws.config",
    "detail-type": "Config Configuration Item Change",
    "detail": {
        "messageType": "ConfigurationItemChangeNotification",
        "configurationItem": {
            "resourceType": "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface",
            "resourceId": [ "eni-030512620140c240d", "eni-0626261dd4743a0fc" ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even now it giving error as 

Inappropriate value for attribute "event_pattern": string required.